# NamedQuery select first in list

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I try to make a namedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Interval.findByMemoryType",
    query = "select i from Interval i JOIN i.intervalDatas id "
    + "where id.fragments.memoryType = :memoryType")
```

My problem is, that fragments is a list of fragment. I'm only interested in memory type of first element in the list.

So I should have something like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Interval.findByMemoryType", 
    query = "select i from Interval i JOIN i.intervalDatas id "
    + "(select first(id.fragments)) as fid) where fid.memoryType = :memoryType")
```

But I get always “The query contains a malformed ending” problem.

Could somebody help me??

Comment: There is no 'first' JPA function I'm aware of, and the subquery assignment should go in the select portion of the query, not in the join.  As the join isn't deterministic, I don't know what value there is to only checking the first fragment in a fragments list.  Don't you want any interval that references a fragment with a certain memorytype?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first result:

```
TypedQuery<Interval> q = em.createQuery ("Interval.findByMemoryType", Interval.class);
q.setParameter("memoryType", memoryType);//+other parameters if you have
Interval interval = q.getSingleResult();
```

The small disadvantage is that it may load all its intervalDatas (depending on the mapping). Also check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult%28%29) for possible exceptions.